# How to display tooltip in knockoutjs when button is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I used CSS to disable the button and I also want to display a tooltip. However just because I disabled the button, I am not able to see my tooltip.

```html
.disabled {
    display: block !important; 
    pointer-events: none; 
    color: #ccc; 
}
```

```html
  <button class="actionButton button primaryBt largeSize" data-bind="click:$root.openStaticVisualizer.bind($root, selectedRoom()), css: { disabled: !displayStaticVisualizer()}, attr:{ title :!displayStaticVisualizer()? ApprovalText: 'test' }">
                <svg class="ico visualizationIcon"><use xlink:href="Content/icons/icons.svg#visualizationIcon" /></svg>
                <span>Visualize Room</span>
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.disabled` class disables all `pointer-events`. This breaks all of the browser's default behaviors that rely on a pointer, like showing a title on hover.

Instead, use the `disabled` attribute. This does *not* block the title from showing, but does disable clicking the button.

You can apply the `disabled` attribute directly through knockout's [disable and enable bindings](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html).

You can apply custom styling by creating a css rule for the [:disabled pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled).

```html
<button
  disabled
  title="This information appears when hovering"
>Hover me for more information</button>
```